# convert dataframe(with one column) to {index -> value}

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have used to_dict() to transform dataframe like this:
[it is very simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDMVF.png)
and I got

```
{'point_dis': {'025ec525073fea4f6433b691c65b45cd': 12365.093765441219,
  '02b697dc2e9214a46aa40e7fb0609310': 2315.3360224791882}
```

what should I do if i just want a dict without  {column -> 
,just the non-nested dict '

```
{'025ec525073fea4f6433b691c65b45cd': 12365.093765441219,
  '02b697dc2e9214a46aa40e7fb0609310': 2315.3360224791882}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select column and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df['point_dis'].to_dict()
print (d)

{'025ec525073fea4f6433b691c65b45cd': 12365.093765441219, 
'02b697dc2e9214a46aa40e7fb0609310': 2315.3360224791882}
```

Or use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and then select nested `dict` by `key`:

```
d = df.to_dict()['point_dis']
print (d)

{'025ec525073fea4f6433b691c65b45cd': 12365.093765441219, 
'02b697dc2e9214a46aa40e7fb0609310': 2315.3360224791882}
```